# AWS Lambda No Space Left on Device

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, delete-file, temp

I am using API gateway to call lambda function that imports a mpeg file (10 mb) from s3 and saves in /tmp folder of lambda and the lambda uploads it to external API (youtube etc)
Recently the API gateway call to lambda is failing intermittently with error

```
[Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Here is how i am downloading the file

`urllib.urlretrieve (s3_mpeg_url, '/tmp/{}'.format(mpeg_filename))`

If i create a new version of that same lambda function and assign to alias API gateway pointing to , it starts to work and again at some point it keeps getting the same error

When i test that lambda function from lambda console it always works

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you deleting the file once you're done with it? Lambda functions can be reused.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your lambda function [has approximately 500MB of disk space available on `/tmp`](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/). However, for performance reasons, AWS Lambda might retain and reuse instances of your function on subsequent calls. There are two possible paths you can take here:

1. If your function is totally stateless (i.e. you don't need the `mpeg` file after uploading it to the external API), just delete it from the `/tmp` folder after the upload.
2. If you need to keep the data around, consider storing it on another media, like S3 or DynamoDB after processing.

Comment: Thanks .. I am looking into option 1 you mentioned but it didnt helped...please pardon my lack of knowledge on deleting files on aws servers... i tried os.remove(/tmp/*.mpeg) but its not working(i am using python in lambda). Can you let me know how we can clear tmp folder

Comment: Don't believe that os.remove() supports wildcards. Delete the file by name, or use some feature of glob.

Comment: that may be it.it wont support wildcards.I used following to get it work       `def emptyDir(folder):
    fileList = os.listdir(folder)
    for f in fileList:
        filePath = folder + '/'+f
        if os.path.isfile(filePath):
            os.remove(filePath)
        elif os.path.isdir(filePath):
            newFileList = os.listdir(filePath)
            for f1 in newFileList:
                insideFilePath = filePath + '/' + f1
            if os.path.isfile(insideFilePath):\n
                os.remove(insideFilePath)`

Comment: Right now, you can configure your ephemeral storage between **512MB** and **10,240MB**. Have in mind that the ephemeral storage is available in each function’s **/tmp** directory.

Answer (score 5):

You can increase the storage from 512MB (default) up to 10,240MB.

**GUI**:
[image: how to change your storage]

**CLI**:

```
 aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name <function_name> \
          --ephemeral-storage '{"Size": 10240}'
```

Note that you are charged for any additional size you incremented.

See full article here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/