# AWS Lambda fails for torch (python)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, torch

All I'm trying to do is create a flask app for [Places365](https://github.com/CSAILVision/places365/blob/master/run_placesCNN_basic.py) and deploy it as an AWS Lambda with API. While everything works fine on my EC-2 instance, Lambda keeps failing with 
`"No module named 'torch': ModuleNotFoundError"` error.

Initially, when I tried to include the torch as part of my virtual environment, Lambda kept failing with `"No space left"` error. So, I uninstalled torch from my virtual environment, redeployed the function and added PyTorch layer (arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:934676248949:layer:pytorchv1-py36:2) to the function. Still, it fails with `"No module named 'torch': ModuleNotFoundError"` error

Also, I used [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) for Lambda deployment

It would be great if someone can share their experience of deploying torch to Lambda

Comment: Could you show us your Lambda? I don't understand how you `include the torch as part of my virtual environment`.

Comment: And the `No space left` error is caused by disk space restriction. [AWS Lambda No Space Left on Device error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347350/aws-lambda-no-space-left-on-device-error?rq=1)

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am also trying to use that pytorch layer in a Zappa app. Did you add the layer manually in the AWS console for your Lambda function?

Comment: @mihow Yes. Pls see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it. Below is what I did

ARN of pytorch layer that I used:
   `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:934676248949:layer:pytorchv1-py36:2`

Added the following code to my python Lambda function

```
  sys.path.insert(1, '/opt')
  import unzip_requirements
  import torch
```